# Specifying the url (port) that a asp.net core 1.0 WebAPI.exe should use in program.cs for both prod and dev

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I am doing the following in my asp.net core 1.0 web api (.NET Framework) program.cs to specify which port I want my web api exe to run in for development purposes only:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseUrls(new string[1] { "http://*:12012" })
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

However, when I publish to production this line causes the WebAPI to error since I want the exe to use the production web-api url i.e. productionWeb/api/values rather than localhost:12012/values

Is there anyway I can get the best of both worlds being able to specify that I want it to run on port 12012 for development purposes and the production url for prod purposes?

My current solution is to just comment out the line before publishing.

Comment: Where are you publishing to?  Azure? your own server?

Comment: Do you run it behind IIS in production? UseUrls should be before UseIISIntegration otherwise you overwrite IIS settings - I described it here: https://blog.3d-logic.com/2016/06/08/running-asp-net-core-applications-with-iis-and-antares/. Note that it is recommended to run ASP.NET Core apps behind a proxy like IIS or nginx

Comment: Yes I am publishing to actual IIS. So you are saying if I change the order I should be good right?

Comment: Yes, changing the order should fix this issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When using IIS you are overwriting the url the IIS (AspNet Core Module) told the app to listen to by calling `.UseUrls()` after `.UseIISIntegration()`. You should change the order of these two calls so that `.UseIISIntegration()` is after `.UseUrl()`. `.UseIISIntegration()` will not touch urls you set if you are not running with IIS so in development your application still will be listening on port 12012. When running with IIS `.UseIISIntegration()` will overwrite the url to listen on the port IIS told it to listen on. I wrote a [post on running Asp.NET Core apps with IIS and Azure Websites](https://blog.3d-logic.com/2016/06/08/running-asp-net-core-applications-with-iis-and-antares/) which explains how things work including this nuance.