# Cannot debug in Visual Studio after changing the port number?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I added the line `.UseUrls("http://*:5000")` to enable clients from other hosts accessing the web api.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseUrls("http://*:5000") // Added
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
```

However, using browser to access `localhost:5000/api/Test` got the error of `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request`? Should the `.UseUrls()` be only compiled for production?

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Mon, 08 Aug 2016 21:42:30 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Server: Kestrel
```

The following messages are copied from Visual studio Output window when testing.

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/api/Test
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISMiddleware:Error: 'MS-ASPNETCORE-TOKEN' does not match the expected pairing token '9bca37f2-7eda-4517-9f8f-60b6cc05cf01', request rejected.
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 8.5976ms 400

Comment: Can you call `UseUrls()` before `UseIISIntegration()`. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37862475/specifying-the-url-port-that-a-asp-net-core-1-0-webapi-exe-should-use-in-progr

Comment: Please confirm if you were running this inside IIS, IISExpress or stand-alone.

Comment: I moved the `UseUrls()` in front of `UseIISIntegration()` and it works when debug run the application name. It still doesn't work if run with IIS express.

Comment: and even after that still same exception or another one?

Answer (score 12):

You should call first `.UseUrls()` and/or `.UseConfig()` and then `.UseIISIntegration()`.

When running ok under IIS/IISExpress, you end up with 2 processes. IIS listening on the desired port and Kestrel on another one. Your requests should go to IIS and then it is forwarded to Kestrel (with the `MS-ASPNETCORE-TOKEN`).

The call to `.UseIISIntegration()` hides this mapping. It actually changes the port in your app and sets `IIS` on the desired port. But it breaks if you call both methods in incorrect order.

You are getting this error message because Kestrel expected to run behind `IIS`, and received a direct request. And it noticed that because `IIS` was not there to inject the `MS-ASPNETCORE-TOKEN` header.

This [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/242) documents the issue and may solve it in future releases.

Comment: This solved it for me. I had the same issue within an hour of op.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve it.
Since the error because `UseKestrel()` and `UseIISIntegration()`, you can try running debug not using IIS/IIS Express, but choose Kestrel server, it will avoid the error happen.
You can check `Properties\launchSettings.json` to find out another debug option.